# Trigger only One element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this DOM:

```
 <article>
   <overlay>
     <IMG>
   </overlay>
   <div class="wrapper">
   </div>
 </article>

<article>
   <overlay>
     <IMG>
   </overlay>
   <div class="wrapper">
   </div>
 </article>
```

In jquery i need to create this function:

```
 $("IMG").on("click", function () 
 {$(".wrapper).CSS("display","block"})
```

But this function has to work only on the clicked element. Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: How do I target the clicked element when they all share the same CSS class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518257/jquery-how-do-i-target-the-clicked-element-when-they-all-share-the-same-css-cla)

Comment: No. DOM is different

Comment: `$("IMG").on("click", function () 
 {$(this).closest('article').find('.wrapper').css('display', 'block');})`

Comment: But the mechanism is the same...

Comment: The key is using `this` to refer to the currently clicked element. Traversing to the wrapper is done as @RyanWilson's comment shows. Note that the method name is `css` not `CSS`. Also you can just use `show()` to do the same thing.

Comment: @Andrew ++++++++----++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/-+

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('img').on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest('article').find('.wrapper').css('display', 'block');
})
```

Comment: How is this any different than what I commented above?

Comment: @RyanWilson It's an answer :P.

Comment: It's not. Your comment was added while I was in the process of writing this answer.